# Adding my SharePoint (on premises) portal to MS Teams as App

Tags: office365, sharepoint-2013, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, microsoft-appstudio

I want to add my portal SharePoint (on-prem) to Microsoft Teams as the app does not tap, I am using `appstudio` app for that but when all steps are complete, the portal does not show (empty page)
although my SharePoint portal authentication is office 365 AUTH (AAD).

Thanks in advance.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you getting any error on console for authentication? Are you planning to add your app as 
a tab in team? Also could you please share the repro steps so that we can try it.

Comment: I didn't understand the question, sorry. But I think this doc [Build Microsoft Teams tab using SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab) will help

Comment: Did you looked into the doc? Is it resolved?

Comment: @Smarter - Can you please provide more detailed repro steps and attach some screenshot of error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

There is an entire framework for doing this now in Teams, if this is for an "intranet" type of experience, called Viva Connections. See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/sharepoint/guide-to-setting-up-viva-connections?culture=en-us&country=WW). It essentially embeds your SharePoint intranet into Teams for everyone in your organisation.

If you're wanting just *any* SharePoint page to be embedded as an "app" experience, I think you need to use a URL that tells Teams what you're trying to do. I've not tested it, but try the steps in [this blog post](https://allesoverteams.nl/kennisbank/blog/embedding-modern-sharepoint-pages-in-microsoft-teams-as-personal-apps-preview/). Specifically notice step 11:

> Content URL – https://[domainUrl]/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest=[pageUrl]
> Update the URL based on your own tenant details. Example URL would be https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest=/sites/theperspective/SitePages/Home.aspx
> The URL will need to be encoded to avoid issues accessing it across different devices.

Update: I didn't read the original post correctly, that this is on premises SharePoint. Not sure if the above will work, but it's easy enough to try it out, and let us know here.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft still search for any help

Comment: @Smarter - Can you please provide more detailed repro steps and attach some screenshot of error you are getting?

Comment: @Smarter - Could you please elaborate on what help you have needed?